# R: Shaping the results of a data import using distinct values in a field

Tags: sql, database, r, parsing, reshape

I have had a good look around on the web but nothing seems to answer the question too clearly. R isn't my usual platform but trying to use it a bit more, starting by replicating some code I have elsewhere in VBA. Below is the extract of an output of a query from a SQL database in R.

```
ID          Return_Date  ISIN              Return
25786       41815        XS1022203076      1.397800e-03
25787       41808        XS1022203076     -4.000600e-03
25977       41815        GB1070308082      9.685500e-03
25978       41808        GB1070308082      2.993700e-03
```

Is there a quick way in R to take the results of the above and get it into the shape shown below? I.E where each of the distinct values in the ISIN field become columns all of which are sorted by values in another field (Return_Date).

```
Return_date    GB1070308082      XS1022203076 
41815          9.685500e-03      1.397800e-03
41808          2.993700e-03     -4.000600e-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, the function you're looking for is `reshape`:

```
reshape(mydf, idvar="Return_Date", timevar="ISIN", 
        direction = "wide", drop="ID")
#   Return_Date Return.XS1022203076 Return.GB1070308082
# 1       41815           0.0013978           0.0096855
# 2       41808          -0.0040006           0.0029937
```

You can also look at `dcast` from "reshape2", for example:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, Return_Date ~ ISIN, value.var="Return")
```